# How do I find the volume of Solid of Revolution for this particular graph?

Tags: volume, solid-of-revolution

I've been given the graph y = $4x - 4x^2$ that has been bound by the x-axis. I've been asked to find the volume of Solid of Revolution about the y-axis using the disc method.

In order to find the inner and outer radii of the disc/washer, I've gotten the question in terms of x as follows:

x = $-\frac{\sqrt{-y+1}-1}{2},\:x=\frac{\sqrt{-y+1}+1}{2}$

Where I'm getting stuck is in knowing which one of these to use for the inner and outer radii. My guess was that I'd use the right side of the graph, given by $x=\frac{\sqrt{-y+1}+1}{2}$ as the outer radius, and subtract that from the left side of the graph, given by x = $-\frac{\sqrt{-y+1}-1}{2}$, but I'm not too sure.

I was wondering if I could get a few pointers on how to approach finding the inner and radii of each washer.

Comment: I would always recommend plotting the graphs to have an intuitive understanding of the situation. You're definitely going in the right direction here.

Comment: When you plot the two solutions for $x(y)$, you can see that solution with the plus sign is the outer radius, and the solution with the negative sign is the inner. Then, you just need to plug these in to the integral.

Comment: Find center of gravity of the parabola and use Pappu's thm

Comment: @Narasimham The OP request to use disk method.

Comment: @Narasimham Never mind, you can also let as an alternative method even if all work reduces to find the area of the parabola (=2/3\cdot 1\cdot 1) since the centroid is at x=1/2 for symmetry. Thus the volume should be $\pi/6$.

Comment: Yes, thats what prompted my first response finding volume the easier way..

Comment: @user9648060 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, the set up should be

$$\int_{0}^{1} \pi [R_2(y)^2-R_1(y)^2)]\,dy=\int_{0}^{1} \pi\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right)^2\right]\,dy$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Find center of gravity of the parabola and use Pappu's thm for the volume, as suggested by gimusi in his comment above.